# image plugin tiny mce editor

Tags: image, tinymce

I was trying to add an image plugin to the tiny mce editor . Added the code snippet to my html.erb file, unable to get the functionality on the editor. why is this happening. This is the code that i wrote

```
<html> 
<head>   
<script src="//cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>
<script>tinymce.init({   selector: "textarea",  // change this value according to your HTML   plugins: "image",   menubar: "insert",   toolbar: "image",   image_list: [     {title: 'My image 1', value: 'http://www.tinymce.com/my1.gif'},     {title: 'My image 2', value: 'http://www.moxiecode.com/my2.gif'}   ] });  </script>
</script> </head> <body>   <textarea>Easy! You should check out MoxieManager!</textarea> </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Full Featured Example on TinyMCE's DOCS.  you need thee `plugins` parameter.

```
tinymce.init({
selector: 'textarea',
  height: 1000,
  menubar: true,
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor textcolor',
    'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code help wordcount'
  ],
  toolbar: 'insert | undo redo |  formatselect | bold italic backcolor  | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help',
  content_css: [
    '../../css/style.css']
});
```